# Frequent refreshing crashes XMLHttpRequest send in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, xmlhttprequest

Our production AngularJS application has been intermittently throwing errors like the following:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$compile/tpload?p0=Templates%2FSecure%2Flanding.html&p1=0&p2=
```

It is also not always that template.  I have found I can reproduce it by rapidly refreshing our website.  When the error occurs it also coincides with the following error messages in the Chrome console:

```
XHR failed loading: GET "https://www.website.com/Templates/Secure/landing.html"
```

Refreshing again, and the template loads just fine.

The website is hosted in IIS 7.5.

I created a new barebones AngularJS website hosted also in IIS and I cannot reproduce the issue there.

Something with the way we've built our website is causing this problem.

I'm hoping someone has some idea about why frequently refreshing a web page would sometimes but not always cause these errors.

**UPDATE:**

I turned on HTTPS for my barebones Angular website and now I can trigger the tpload error by frequently refreshing the website!  Not sure what this means but HTTPS / SSL is involved in some way.

**UPDATE 2:**

I used nodejs to host the aforementioned barebones Angular website instead of IIS, using SSL, and the problem goes away!  So, there is something about hosting the app in IIS 7.5 with SSL that is causing frequent refreshes to result in the above errors.